# Seperate Objects in local storage Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-chrome, local-storage

I currently have an item in local storage which looks like this

```
"cars":[
{
"Id":7,
"Name":"Audi",
},
{
"Id":8,
"Name":"Ford",
}
```

I want to retrieve all of the Id's only and store them in a string.
At the minute I am pulling the data like this:

```
var cars = "";
cars= localStorage.getItem('cars');
var carArr= new Array();
carArr.push(cars);
```

How can I just obtain the Id's

Comment: You need to look at [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: can you show what you get when you log `cars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` only supports `strings`. So, you have to use `JSON.parse` to get the cars array from string and then use `array#map` to get all the ids.

```
var carsString = localStorage.getItem('cars');
var cars = JSON.parse(carsString);

var ids = cars.map( car => car.Id);
console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly, you have to use [**Array.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform your array in combination with [**JSON.parse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [**JSON.stringify**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to read/write from the storage.

Here is an example using a "mocked" localStorage:

```js
// use a mock storage because snippet doesn't allow localStorage usage.
var mockStorage = {};

// setup initial storage
try {
  mockStorage.cars = JSON.stringify([
    {
      Id:7,
      Name:"Audi",
    },
    {
      Id:8,
      Name:"Ford",
    }
  ]);
} catch(e) {}
console.log('inital local storage:\n', mockStorage);


// example

var cars = [];

// parse JSON string value from storage to javascript object.
try {
  cars = JSON.parse(mockStorage.cars)
} catch(e) {}
console.log('cars:\n', cars);
// transform array of cars to array of car ids
var ids = cars.map(car => car.Id)
console.log('car ids:\n', ids);
// transform array to JSON string
try {
  mockStorage.cars = JSON.stringify(ids);
} catch(e) {}
console.log('local storage:\n', mockStorage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```js
//you get this from localStorage after you parse it
//JSON.parse(localStorage.cars);
var cars = [
{
"Id":7,
"Name":"Audi",
},
{
"Id":8,
"Name":"Ford",
}];
var res = [];
cars.forEach(function(val){
  res.push(val.Id);
});

console.log(res);
```