# How to store a full object in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to create a function with two arguments, and I want to use the variables to define a local storage object. How do I do this? 
This is what I have now (no function)

```
localStorage.setItem("Name", "Sandy");
localStorage.setItem("Last Name", "Smith");
var valueOfName = localStorage.getItem("Name");
var valueOfLastName = localStorage.getItem("Last Name");
```

Comment: Wrap what you have in a `function`?

Comment: Is this for Node JS? because browsers already have such a `localStorage` object builtin

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094597/seperate-objects-in-local-storage-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function that takes two values and stores them in localStorage:

```
function storeFullName(firstName, lastName) {
  localStorage.setItem("Name", firstName);
  localStorage.setItem("Last Name", lastName);
}

storeFullName("Sandy", "Smith");
```

To get the values from the storage you'll need to use `localStorage.getItem("Name");` and `localStorage.getItem("Last Name");`

### Edit

If you want to retreive both values using a single function you can write a function that will wrap the values in an object:

```
function getFullNameObject() {
  var name = localStorage.getItem("Name");
  var lastName = localStorage.getItem("Last Name");
  return { "name": name, "lastName": lastName };
}
```

Then you could get the values from the object like this:

```
var fullNameObject = getFullNameObject();
```

and then if you want you can get the values from the object into other variables like this:

```
var name = fullNameObject.name;
var lastName = fullNameObject.lastName;
```